# Elasticsearch escape "¬" character in regex

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I am stuck with this symbol "¬" when trying to run a elasticsearch regex query
to return from set of record in format "prefix-content¬value".

Example (not limited to website pattern, can be any value) : "website-website descriptions that not required¬www.google.com" .

```
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "query": {
            "match_all": {}
         },
         "filter": {
            "regexp": {
              "information": "(website?)(.*¬)(www.google.com?)"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Has anyone encounter such problem before and manage to handle this ? Thanks.

Comment: So you need to filter out websites that are not like `www.google.com`?

Comment: You might be in charset encoding mismatch territory, as that char is in the extended ASCII range.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the problem with  **"¬"**, could you post `mapping` of the filed _information_ and some sample documents that you think should match for your regex